# How can I give a file a custom icon?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-8, windows-vista, icons

[image]

I would like a way to give a file a custom icon.

I know it's possible to change the icons for an entire file type, but that's not what I want.

I know it's possible to create a shortcut to a file, and give that a custom icon, but that's no good either (and gets the little shortcut overlay on it too).

I'd like to know if there's a way to take a normal file like a `.txt`, `.doc`, or `.xlsx` file an icon other than that of the default icon for that extension.

Failing that, is there an easy way to create a script or very tiny application wrapper around a normal file which launches it normally? (since applications can have their own icons)

Comment: You need to tell us which version of Windows you are using please.

Comment: @JulianKnight This request pertains to XP, Vista, 7, 8, and 8.1

Answer (score 0):

i didn't tested this soft yet, but got this link for u.
Mostly i think it works for windows xp.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PD8UIs9Ycyw

soft to download

http://icolorfolder.en.softonic.com/

As stated in video link, it not only customizes the color of the folders but it can also change the  icons.

Hope it works for u :)

Comment: The video shows a context menu with the words "change icon", but never is it actually shown changing the icon. From feedback in the comments it appears as though that feature doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can remove shortcut overlay by this file saved with **.reg** extension and launched:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]
"29"="%windir%\\System32\\shell32.dll,-50"
```

This creates the wrapper you expect without potentially distracting overlay.

To restore the overlay back:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]
"29"=-
```

Source: [howtogeek.com](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-shortcut-icon-arrow-overlay-in-windows-vista/)